# I have a lateinit error "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dialog has not been initialized"

Tags: kotlin

I got a message "kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dialog has not been initialized" in this code

```
  class AlarmClock : Application() {
      var serviceBinder: AlarmService.AlarmBinder? = null
  
      override fun onCreate() {
          super.onCreate()
          instance = this
          Util.ringtones += Util.getRingtones(this)

          val si = Intent(this, AlarmService::class.java).apply {
              action = Constants.ActionInit
          }

          bindService(si, Connection(this), Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE or Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT)
      }

      class Connection(val parent: AlarmClock) : ServiceConnection {
          override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
              parent.serviceBinder = null
          }

          override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName?, service: IBinder?) {
              parent.serviceBinder = service as? AlarmService.AlarmBinder
              parent.serviceBinder?.also { binder ->
                  ServiceListeners.forEach { it(binder) }
              }
          }
      }

      fun doWithService(func: (AlarmService.AlarmBinder) -> Unit) {
          if (serviceBinder != null) {
              func(serviceBinder!!)
          } else {
              ServiceListeners += func
          }
      }

      companion object {
          val gson = Gson()
          val ServiceListeners = mutableListOf<(AlarmService.AlarmBinder) -> Unit>()
          **lateinit var instance: AlarmClock**
              private set
      }
  }
```

The error appear when i add alarm or disable alarm with point out "lateinit var instance: AlarmClock",i think instance doesn't work with service code

```
 class AlarmService : Service(), SensorEventListener {

     private lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences

     val timer = Timer("AlarmClock")
     val alarms = mutableListOf<Alarm>()

     var current: Alarm? = null
     var mp: MediaPlayer? = null
     val handler = Handler()
     var sm: SensorManager? = null

     override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
         preferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PreferencesAlarms,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
         when (intent.action) {
             Constants.ActionInit -> {
                 val alarmList = preferences.getStringSet(Constants.AlarmList, emptySet())
                 alarms += alarmList.mapNotNull { gson.fromJson(preferences.getString(it, ""), Alarm::class.java) }

                 var c = Calendar.getInstance()
                 val delay = 60 - c.get(Calendar.SECOND)

                 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
                     override fun run() {
                         c = Calendar.getInstance()
                         val h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                         val m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
                         val d = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

                         alarms.filter { it.enabled }.forEach {
                             if (it.timeH == h && it.timeM == m && (it.activeOnDay(d) || !it.repeat.values.contains(true))) {
                                 val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("mm-hh-dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US)
                                 Log.i("WHAT THE FUCK", it.lastTime + "?=" + timestamp.format(Date()))
                                 if (it.lastTime != timestamp.format(Date())) {
                                     current = it
                                     startAlarm(it.id)
                                 }

                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }, delay * 1000L, 1000)
             }
         }

         return AlarmBinder(this)
     }

     override fun onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy()
         sm?.unregisterListener(this)
     }

     fun startAlarm(id: String) {
         mp = MediaPlayer().also {
             it.isLooping = true
         }
         val alarm = gson.fromJson(preferences.getString(id, ""), Alarm::class.java)
         val volume = alarm.volume.toFloat() / 100

         try {
             mp?.setDataSource(this@AlarmService, Uri.parse(alarm.ringtoneUri))
             mp?.prepare()
             mp?.setVolume(volume, volume)
             mp?.start()
         } catch (e: IOException) {
             mp = null
         }

         if (current?.snoozeOnMove == true) {
             sm = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
             val accelerometer = sm?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION)

             sm?.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)
         }

         val timestamp = SimpleDateFormat("mm-hh-dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US)
         alarm.lastTime = timestamp.format(Date())

         if (!alarm.repeat.values.contains(true)) {
             alarm.enabled = false
         }
         val alarmData = AlarmClock.gson.toJson(alarm)
         preferences.edit().also {
             it.putString(id, alarmData)
         }.apply()
         alarms.removeAll { it.id == id }
         alarms += alarm

         val intent = Intent(this, AlarmActive::class.java)
         intent.putExtra(Constants.AlarmID, id)
         startActivity(intent)
     }

     class AlarmBinder(val service: AlarmService) : Binder() {
         var snoozeListener: SnoozeListener? = null

         fun refreshAlarms() {
             service.alarms.clear()
             val alarmList = service.preferences.getStringSet(Constants.AlarmList, emptySet())
             service.alarms += alarmList.mapNotNull { gson.fromJson(service.preferences.getString(it, ""), Alarm::class.java) }
         }

         fun snoozeAlarm() {
             if (service.current?.snoozeTime ?: 0 > 0) {
                 snoozeListener?.onSnooze()
                 service.mp?.stop()

                 service.handler.postDelayed({
                     service.mp?.start()
                 }, service.current?.snoozeTime!! * 60000L)
             }
         }

         fun stopAlarm() {
             service.current = null
             service.sm?.unregisterListener(service)
             service.mp?.stop()
         }
     }

     override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
         if (event.sensor.type == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {
             val x = event.values[0]
             val y = event.values[1]
             val z = event.values[2]

             val diff = Math.sqrt((x * x + y * y + z * z).toDouble())
                  if (diff > 0.5) {
                 **AlarmClock.instance.doWithService** {
                     it.snoozeAlarm()
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     interface SnoozeListener {
         fun onSnooze()
     }
 
     companion object {
         val gson = Gson()
     }

     override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {}
 }
```

Could you check what's wrong and teach me what i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess. Since I see you're setting the `AlarmClock.instance` in `AlarmClock.onCreate()`, the instance should be set fine *unless* you forgot to set this class as the Application class in the manifest.

In the `<application>` element, you should put `android:name=".AlarmClock"`.